# Django filter objects group by day

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I am trying to filter a user activity against the date. Suppose I have a check in/out functionality in my application. When listing out the logs I wanted to show up each day's activities differently.

Anyone ever tried this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, please share your code, to add our contribution into that.

Comment: This is built-in functionality. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#date

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your data in a DataField you could easily achieve it with the following code :

```
import pandas as pd

# Feel free to change periods and start day
Period = pd.period_range('2018-01', periods=200, freq='D')
for day in Period:
    YourObject.objects.filter(datetime__startswith=day)
```

I change the code a bit more to optimize the Queries number.

So you could run this code snippet :

```
query = YourObject.objects.all()
for index, item in enumerate(query):
    if index > 0:
        previous = query[index - 1]
        if previous.datetime.month == item.datetime.month and previous.datetime.day == item.datetime.day:
            # Same day do stuff
        else:
            # Another day do stuff
```

Finally, if you have more than one year add the code below in your second if statement `previous.datetime.year == item.datetime.year and`

Hope it helps

Comment: Why query in loop? This will query to the database server 200 times. It can be achieved in single query, this solution will be very slow.

Comment: Optimize my answer. Let me know if this improves the performance. @AnupYadav